# ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm having an import error when trying to run a script that imports Basemap from mpl_toolkits.basemap.  The error seems to lie with _geoslib.so trying to find libgeos-3.4.2.dylib; However, in my /usr/local/lib directory, I have libgeos-3.5.0.dylib.

Any ideas on how to get _geoslib.so to recognize that I'm using a different libgeos?  I've tried to uninstall and install matplotlib, basemap, and geos, but I haven't had any luck yet.  The error message is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python1.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _geoslib
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm running Python2.7 on a Mac OSX, with matplotlib installed using homebrew.

Comment: What do you get for ``otool -L /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so``? When reinstalling packages with ``pip install``, try using the ``--no-cache`` option to ensure you aren't installing a cached/pre-compiled package which is already setup to use library from wrong location.

Comment: Hi Graham, I get the following:
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so:
 /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.2.0)
 /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.4.2.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)`


I will try the --no-cache option as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem and updating basemap did the trick for me. 
I hope this helps. 
Cheers

Comment: Do you mind adding some more details to your answer? How you updated the basemap and what difference it made? It would make the answer more helpful